# Fail2ban jailed but IP still accessing server

Tags: iptables, ubuntu-16.04, fail2ban, webmin

I've got a server running a bunch of WordPress sites, and each of these sites refuse logins from IP's after a number of failed logins. The steps are as follows:

1. 3 failed logins from an IP = WP refuses logins from this IP for 10mins (level 1 lockout)
2. On the 2nd level 1 lockout, this moves to level 2 upon which the IP is refused for 1hour

Additionally, the WP security plugin writes to a file on the server(Level 3?). This means we can pool data across sites hosted on that server. Now using Fail2Ban we look for 3 level 3 lockouts within 1 month and then ban at server level for 3 months.

However, the WP plugins are still showing repeat new lockouts for these same IP addresses. This means that the perpetrator is still gaining access to sites hosted on this server.

If I look in the server logs I can see that the lockouts are being written to the correct file. I can also see that Fail2Ban and the relevant jail/actions are detecting the repeat IPs/offender(s) and banning them.

Now, if I run the following command:

```
iptables -L
```

I get output similar to this(edited for brevity):

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)
target     prot opt source               destination         
f2b-WordPress  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere            multiport dports http,https
f2b-Http-Get-Dos  tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             multiport dports http,https
.....
```

and further down:

```
Chain f2b-WordPress (1 references)
target     prot opt source               destination         
REJECT     all  --  dedic980.hidehost.net  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
REJECT     all  --  dedic693.hidehost.net  anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

So, I can see that my jail is being triggered, and that the hostname related to the IP's used are being rejected, but the user is still gaining access to the server on the same IP's that have been used repeatedly. So, clearly they are still getting access to the sites on the server and are trying to brute force their way into the site admins.

This needs to be stopped, asap.

So, my assumption is that iptables is blocking the hostname and not the IP. Since, this hostname appears to be from a service designed to hide real hostnames I figured this is the cause of the problem ie: iptables is blocking the wrong hostname. But perhaps I'm wrong here... I'd welcome a better solution if that's the case.

On that basis I've edited /etc/fail2ban/jail.conf as follows (i know I should create a local version):

```
# "usedns" specifies if jails should trust hostnames in logs,
#   warn when DNS lookups are performed, or ignore all hostnames in logs
#
# yes:   if a hostname is encountered, a DNS lookup will be performed.
# warn:  if a hostname is encountered, a DNS lookup will be performed,
#        but it will be logged as a warning.
# no:    if a hostname is encountered, will not be used for banning,
#        but it will be logged as info.
# usedns = warn
usedns = no
```

Then, I saved everything and restarted the fail2ban service. The logs files suggest that everything is running fine and that the wordpress jail did it's job and banned the 2 IP's being used by this particular person.

Another look at `iptables -L` however shows that the hostname has been blocked and not the IP's.....

So, what do I do now?

***Update***

I've just added the two IP's manually to iptables via Webmin > Linux Firewall (which I think uses firewalld) and run `iptables -L` which shows the hostnames rather than the IP's I entered. So, is this iptables converting the IP's to hostnames rather than fail2ban. If so, why is it that the other 20 IP's i've added rules for manually all show as their IP and NOT a hostname?

Comment: Use `iptables -L -n` to disable host name resolving.

Comment: Thanks, I just spotted that elsewhere. Doesn't it simply show the results without the resolution? So are IP's or hostnames stored? Any ideas why these IP's aren't being blocked / why this IP based user is still able to reach these sites?

Comment: The hostname is only displayed to you as a convenience (or inconvenience). It is not actually used to make any firewall decisions.

Answer (score 2):

The rules will block new connections, not existing connections.  As long as they keep the connection alive they will be able to make queries.

To drop their existing connections add a copy of the reject rule above the accept rule for established connections.  Remove the rule once the connections are dropped.

You should be able to see the connections in the output of the command 'netstat -ant | grep EST' .

You may need to manually add a rule if they keep trying.  Fail2ban only bans connection for the period specified by the bantime setting.  A manually added rule should stick.

Comment: Thanks for that info. However my drop rule is above the accept rules. Also, using the command given in your answer only shows 4 normal looking connections and nothing from the two IP's that I'm trying to block.

Comment: @PhillHealey Normally the very first rule accepts established and related packets. The rest of the rules follow that.  To drop established connections you need a rule above that. The netstat command will only report currently open connections. Compare the times form the access log with the fail2ban log messages.